# When I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum I get a weird error

Tags: iphone, error-handling, uiimage, save, nserror

After I call it using any UIImage I receive this error: `Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3304 "Failed to encode image for saved photos." UserInfo=0x17de90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to encode image for saved photos.}`

anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Show the code you are using to save the photo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the error was that I was saving an image that was 0 width and 0 height and i fixed that and it worked.